# MySql determine all elements of string list exists in other string list

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have these tables:

```
category_table
+--------+-----------------+---------+
| id     | title         | parent_id |
+--------+---------------+-----------+
| 1      | f             | null      |
| 2      | h             | null      |
| 3      | j             | 1         |
| 4      | y             | 3         |
| 5      | d             | 3         |
+--------+-----------------+---------+

post_table
+--------+---------------+-------------+
| id     | title         | categoryies |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
| 1      | title1        | 1           |
| 2      | title2        | 1,2         |
| 3      | title3        | 4,5         |
| 4      | title4        | 4           |
| 5      | title5        | 3           |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

and a procedure that find all posts that has `'3,5,2'` categories.

how procedure will search string list in other string list similar to:

```
Create Procedure post_select(IN category_ids Varchar(200))
Begin
   Select *
   From post
   Where 
   // all category_ids exists in post categories column
   // such as FIND_IN_SET('1', '1,2,3') but first parameter
   // should be list string for example:
   // FIND_IN_SET('2,3,4','2,4,5,6,7,8')

End;
```

Comment: @Gunaseelan Who cares? Until the schema is fixed, there's no point 'trying' anything!

Comment: Stop. See normalisation.

Comment: This question needs some clarification (and some typo fixing too). Do you want the procedure to receive a parameter with a comma-separated string that's interpreted as a list of values, of which any will make the row appear in the result? Also it's helpful to demonstrate the desired result, to cross-check if we understand it right.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a post_category table where you store the post_id together with the category_id.

Comment: I need comma separated search but don't have any function for searching list in other list ...

Comment: @SLDev If you need that, don't bother using an RDBMS.

Comment: @SLDev The point is simple. Either normalise your schema, or don't use a relational database management system; there's nothing wrong with using comma separated lists, and there's nothing wrong with using relational databases; just don't try to use both together.